hop.nvim: using :HopWord with operators?
(I'm using https://github.com/smoka7/hop.nvim)
It says in the documentation "Use it with commands like v, d, c, y" but with the sample init.lua config below, It doesn't work. I mapped the , key to :HopWord, but when I try d, or c, it doesn't work.
-- LazyNvim Setup
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not (vim.uv or vim.loop).fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)
require("lazy").setup({
  {
    'smoka7/hop.nvim',
    version = "*",
    opts = {
      keys = 'etovxqpdygfblzhckisuran'
    }
  },
})

vim.keymap.set({"n", "v"}, ',', function() vim.cmd(":HopWord") end, { noremap = true, desc = 'move to word in buffer' })


I just needed to search a bit more. I found a comment from the dev in an issue where they say you need an operator mapping. This works: vim.keymap.set({"n", "v", "o"}, ',', function() vim.cmd(":HopWord") end, { noremap = true, desc = 'move to word in buffer' }).
